# Stop is returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an "auto-suggest" input. On `keyup` in a `setTimeout` function an ajax request will be made. If the key is <kbd>enter</kbd> then a search is desired and the suggestions should be hidden.

The problem is, that if I type fast enough, when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> the "auto-suggest" will still be shown. I am guessing that the second `keyup` (enter) is triggered *before* the first handler has the chance to stop execution, so first the search is triggered and only *after* this is the "auto-suggest" triggered.

How can I prevent the program to return and execute the first handler?

**Edit**

Here is a part of the code:

```
    searchTextInput.bind("keyup.qssb", function(event){
      clearTimeout(suggestTimeout);
      switch(event.keyCode){
        case 40: <select option down>; break;
        case 38: <select option up>; break
        case 13: jQuery(widget).trigger("search"); break;
        default: <do some things>;
                 suggestTimeout = setTimeout(startSearch, 200); break;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Could you show your code/dom?

Comment: `clearTimeout()`, or an `if` in the callback.

Comment: @SLaks please see my edit. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is really what you described, then there are two things you could do (together) to address it:

1. When you send an ajax request, you store the reference to that request.  When you receive another *keyup*, cancel that ajax request.
2. When you start executing the *onEnter* handler, set some variable to indicate that auto-suggestions are no longer needed.  In the auto-suggest handler, after your ajax returns, only show the suggestions if that variable is not set.

Essentially, your code structure would be like this **(note that this is pseudocode and is not meant to be copied into your application)**:

```
var ajaxReq == null;
var needSuggestions = true;

$('#textfield').on("keyup", function(e) {
    if(ajaxReq != null) {
        ajaxReq.abort();
        ajaxReq = null;
    }

    if(key is enter) {
        needSuggestions = false;
        execute search;
    }
    else {
        ajaxReq = $.ajax(...,
            done: function() { ajaxReq = null; }
            success: function(data) {
                if(needSuggestions) {
                    display suggestions;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is, tha(considering your code) at the first trigger, I get on the "else" branch(the one with ajax) but BEFORE having the request sent, I have another trigger, which is enter, so the search is executed. After executing search, we come back into the stack and execute the ajax call from the first event(the else branch). Or, at least this is what it seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Dragos This is not true. Because enter key was pressed _after_ another key, your ajax will start _before_ the next call.  My advice is to try it.

Comment: Please see the snippet I've added to the question. It seems to me that this is precisely what I'm doing. Or am I missing something? Is my code not similar to yours?

Comment: @Dragos No, this is not what you are doing.  You are clearing the timeout on the next key press, but if the time has arrived and the ajax has started, then it's still executing.  I am not sure why you even need the timeout in the first place.

Comment: Hmmm. You're right. I haven't really thought too much about that case. Thank you for the suggestion. The timeout is added for a similar reason and it should save some unneeded requests too. Anyway, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It's an excellent use case for debouncing function. Only start the request for auto suggestoin, when the user stopped typing for let's say 300ms. See [_.debounce()](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) for example